# MySQL sandbox strace option

Tags: mysql, strace

Latest MySQL Sandbox version uses environment variable SBDEBUG to start mysql instances in debug mode, but i can't pass mysql --debug option.

```
export SBDEBUG=d:t:O,/tmp/client.trace
cd ~/sandboxes/msb_5_6_13
./start
```

I want to get strace output. How can i do that ? 
Links:

- [SBDEBUG](http://datacharmer.blogspot.com/2009/03/mysql-sandbox-approaching-version-3.html)
- [MySQL trace files](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/making-trace-files.html)
- [MySQL Sandbox](http://search.cpan.org/~gmax/MySQL-Sandbox-3.0.40/lib/MySQL/Sandbox.pm#Environment_variables)

Comment: ? What do you mean with "you cannot pass --debug". Edit whatever is contained in ./start?

Comment: i can't pass --debug variable to mysqld through mysql-sandboxes "./start" script

Answer (score 1):

You can probably try starting the server normally with `--debug` flag, get it's PID using `ps aux` or `pgrep`, then use strace to attach to that running process using `strace -p $PID`. You also probably want to follow forks/child processes with the `-f` flags to strace. Here is a handy [cheat sheet](http://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2015/11/15/strace-cheat-sheet/) for strace that I like to use.